# Access Token Expiration settings have no effect

Tags: rest-api, magento2.4.4, oauth, token, access

I tried to change the default customer access token expiration from 1 hour to 48 hours and even to 0 to disable expiration, but regardless of what number I enter, the token I receive from the REST API expires in 1 hour. I cleaned the cache, flushed it.

What can I do to make Magento use the numbers I enter? (Magento 2.4.4)

[image: My current settings in Magento]

This is how the API request looks like:

```
POST https://elszerbt.alphadev.hu/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{"username": "jonatan@alphadev.hu", "password": "mypassword"}
```

The customer has been added manually and the password setup through the activation email link. This test customer is the only one right now:

[image: List of customers]

The token works perfectly once it's received, but it expires early. You can see the token here:

```
eyJraWQiOiIxIiwiYWxnIjoiSFMyNTYifQ.eyJ1aWQiOjEsInV0eXBpZCI6MywiaWF0IjoxNjYwNzI5ODQ0LCJleHAiOjE2NjA3MzM0NDR9.fxnGiLwFNc4dAZA0-npEsAf0gzpnU1pKXZke78WFuOM
```

If you enter this token to https://jwt.io/, you can see the difference between the issue date and expiration date is 1 hour.

I also tested the admin token the following way:

```
POST https://elszerbt.alphadev.hu/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{"username": "adminuser", "password": "mypassword"}
```

What's interesting is that it also expires in 1 hour, which is not the default setting for admin tokens. The default is 4 hours.

This is the admin token I received:

```
eyJraWQiOiIxIiwiYWxnIjoiSFMyNTYifQ.eyJ1aWQiOjEsInV0eXBpZCI6MiwiaWF0IjoxNjYwNzMwMTY5LCJleHAiOjE2NjA3MzM3Njl9.dwI7qbYSe8A2BOHlLKE4KlL7QmJzlX1wYVlkoRJIhyM
```

I have this issue on multiple instances, although they have exactly the same setup. I'm using the default file-system cache of Magento.

Comment: are you able to add more info on how to reproduce your issue? How is the API call you make? header, body, endpoint will be useful to ensure we can replicate exactly your issue?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I added more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. There is another setting here:

[image: Other configuration page]

I set the expiration here to 600 minutes and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a setting in your redis configuration.

please check your redis settings in your env.php.

documentation can be found here: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cache/redis/redis-pg-cache.html

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but I'm not using redis, the caching is set to default.

Comment: Any ideas how can I determine if it's a caching problem?

Answer (score 0):

The setting for the Token expiration can be found in `Store/Configuration/Services/OAuth`

See screenshot below,

[image]

Comment: No, it's not. That's my exact point. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: I believe you must have a customisation taking over this behaviour in Magento as it seems fine at my end

Answer (score 0):

```
module:disable Magento_JwtUserToken Magento_AdobeStockAdminUi Magento_AdminAdobeIms
```

That will make the token not reset.